# URL as a string and values in Xcode

Tags: ios, parsing, web, service

I am working on a web service app and i have a question. I am calling a specific Url site with the following code:

```
NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:[requestStream stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:Url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Then i create an nsstring and print it with the NSLog and i got the following results:

```
2014-05-14 15:50:58.118 jsonTest[1541:907] Data : Array
(
    [url] => http://sheetmusicdb.net:8000/hnInKleinenGruppen
    [encoding] => MP3
    [callsign] => SheetMusicDB.net - J
    [websiteurl] => 
)
```

My question in how can i parse the URL link and then use it as a value? I tried to put them to an array or a dictionary but i get error back. So if anyone can help me i would appreciate it.

Ok i managed to grab the link with the following code:

```
if(htmlString) {
    //NSLog(@"HTML %@", htmlString);

    NSRange r = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"=>"];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange r1 = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"[encoding]"];
        if (r1.location != NSNotFound) {
            if (r1.location > r.location) {
                _streamTitle = [htmlString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(r), r1.location - NSMaxRange(r))];
                NSLog(@"Title %@", _streamTitle);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions. My problem now is that i pass the string into an avplayer and i can't hear music.

Comment: its not proper response

Comment: What exactly do you mean Kirit?

Comment: use JSON parsing, its better for you.

Comment: Can you give me your URL

Comment: Yes this is the URL with JSON request:http://www.dar.fm/uberstationurl.php?station_id=32109&partner_token=6706934994@callback=json

Answer (score 3):

I think this will be help for you..

```
// @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
// @synthesize responseData;

NSString *urlString=@"http:your urls";
self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] delegate:self];
NSLog(@"connection====%@",connection);
```

JSON Delegates :

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
   [self.responseData setLength:0];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
    self.responseData=nil;
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
      NSArray *response_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

  //  Write code for retrieve data according to your Key.
 }
```

Comment: Eesdee i tried your example and after NSArray i wrote the following code with no results. It returns NULL. NSDictionary* arrayDic = [response_Array objectAtIndex:0];NSString * arrayStr = [arrayDic objectForKey:@"Array"];
    NSLog(@"JSON url = %@", arrayStr);

Comment: eesdee here is a valid url after a search of my implementation http://gr-relay-12.gaduradio.pl/25

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uRL"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        if (theConnection)
        {
            receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain] ;
        }


#pragma mark - Connection Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    // append the new data to the receivedData
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    //NSLog(@"data %@",data);
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // release the connection, and the data object
    //    [connection release];
    //    [receivedData release];

    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:[error localizedDescription]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [prompt show];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[receivedData bytes]
                                                  length:[receivedData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];


    }

}
```